# adding limiter to reduce distortion in audio amp

Tags: pcb, audio, amplifier, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication

I got this [schematic](https://learn.adafruit.com/system/assets/assets/000/015/174/original/adafruit_products_schem.png?1394655002) from adafruit. But at high volumes, it exhibits distortion.
A guy from Maxim Integrated referred to include a [diode-resistor network](http://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/an/AN4551.pdf)(BAV99 and R-100 Ohm) b/w C22/C23 and R8/R9(to be placed exactly as in the PDF).

Adafruit however reconfirmed it by saying, since it is a stereo amp, it should be b/w INL & AGND, and INR & AGND. That is, two of those.

I cant seem to figure out the exact placement in the PCB layout.  In the schematic however I presume it should be placed as if, the [BAV99](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/BA/BAV99.pdf) output pin no. 3 to be b/w C22/R8 and pin 1&2 with R of 100 Ohm connected to AGND.
Then another output pin of BAV99 b/w C23/R9 and the other pins with AGND. I hope you can make out.

But I cant figure out with the PCB layout.

[MAX9744 Datasheet](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/MAX9744.pdf)

Here are the layers and [PCB screenshot](https://learn.adafruit.com/system/assets/assets/000/015/175/original/adafruit_products_fabprint.png?1394655365).
- [Copper Top](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hkmpppmljygwhwm/copper-top.png)
- [Mask Top](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x7v9vd9nta3zuig/mask-top.png)
- [Silk Top](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eey1l2t6e1ktj3i/silk-top.png)
- [Copper Bottom](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kzbgxz2sdy5k11y/copper-bottom.png)
- [Mask Bottom](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hj7kqqodctuiji1/mask-bottom.png)

([Online Paint](http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/stable/editor/svg-editor.html) if required to explain)

Answer (score 2):

You do realize, I hope, that the problem is that you're overdriving the inputs, right? and that a diode network will not prevent that, just make the results a little less nasty? And that the real solution is not to ask for too much output from the board?

OK, so you want to do it anyway. I hope you've got good eyesight and a steady hand.

Looking at the PCB screenshot, the input connector is the 3-pin connector at the upper left. The signals are carried on the upper and lower pins, while the center pin is ground. You can see the two signal traces going right and down to your 2 capacitors just under the 5-pin IC. The right-hand pad of each capacitor is where you want to make your connection.

Good luck.